# Activity vs Fragments again. Separate logic and make app smooth

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

sorry for asking this question again. I have read all related articles, but haven't figured out what is better to use and when.
My app is going to be online store native client.
So I have a bunch of different screens in my app.

1. First Screen. It will be main screen like in the most online stores. There will be image slider, last new products, sales, ad and other common stuff for store.
2. Second screen. There will be simple list of categories in the store, without any ad,sliders and so on. Only list (RecyclerView).
3. Third screen. Will represent description of product, price, photos and other.
4. Fourth screen. Login and sign up screen to let user login in it's account.

There would be a lot of other screens required for native store client.
I have some questions about this.

1. I have watched the video, where lecturer said that in their app they are using only one activity for all app except settings and payment. So it makes app smoother, responsive because fragments are more lightweight that fragments. Okey, in this case we have base Activity, it should implement all callbacks from fragments to handle data and replace screen with another fragment.
   We can use event bus to make it easier to with callbacks, but there is another problem.
2. How my activity layout should be built, it should have one fragment container and we can replace whole screen with another fragment or activity should include several fragments. For example for each image slider, ad, last products use its own fragment?
3. If we will use one container, so in this case we change whole screen. Is there any benefit of using fragment in this case ?
4. If use several fragment per screen. We have to put them in parent framgent ? In this case we are dealing with nested fragments. In most cases it is bad practice to do so.
5. Or we have just to know about all fragments currently present on the screen and when we have to change all screen view remove all old fragments and add new ?
6. What about nested fragments? Is bad to use them, and I have to do my best to get rid of them ?

Please explain how to build app to make it responsive but also to make code pattern and best practices oriented.
Thanks everyone for the help in advance.

Comment: Could you post the link to the video of the 'one activity app'?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Just as a heads up this question is a hugely broad topic.  I highly recommend reading through these as well: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask they are both fantastic resources to use when asking or answering questions!  For specifics about what you can ask about you can also take a read through http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried both ways, each for long period of time! I think both ways of developing applications are completely okey! I prefer fragments mostly because app looks and feels smoother but working with fragments may add a little bit of complexity to your application especially in your first project.

Should you have only one container in activity? Yes! because it doesn't matter how complex your app is, you always have some simple pages like about us, contact us, etc. and most likely they need to be full screen size! So your main activity should only have one container.

Is using nested fragment a bad idea? No! there is nothing wrong with nested fragments, in fact using nested fragments correctly will reduce the complexity of your app, that's because your main activity doesn't have to worry about little details in fragments, there transitions, navigation, etc.

Is using multiple fragment in one screen okey? again yes! that's the beauty of fragments, you arrange them as you like. Only ask one question before using multiple fragment in a screen. Do i need fragments or i just need to combine some views together?! In second case you don't need fragment, You can build a custom view that's combine some views together. (for example two textviews and one button for logging screen). Now instead of login fragment you have logginView than you can use like any other view.

Last thing you should know is using one activity increases the chance you get memory leaks (in particular activity leak) and when you get a memory leak it will be harder to find and handle it. why? because every fragment has a reference to activity (remember method getActivity?) so if you leak any fragment you also leak the activity and since your activity contains a lot of things you leak all of them all together!! And also all views have a reference to context. So again if you leak one view by accident, you leaked everything!! So be very careful about memory leaks. here is a detailed artical about memory leaks here http://goo.gl/7YDCK7